# linux (red hat) compare directories and copy over files that are different

Tags: linux

I basically want rsync, but don't have the luxury of being able to install it.

But I need a way to deploy files from one server to another.  I edit one or more files on one server and then need to copy all modified files to another server by comparing files that aren't the same (and being able to exclude .htaccess files)

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: If there is a compiler available you could just build rsync and use locally without installing it. It has no dependencies besides a working compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I will assume that you have shell access to both servers)

You do not need to install `rsync` system-wide. You can install it in your home-directory. First get a copy of the `rsync` binary for your distribution:

- You can extract it from the `rsync` RPM package using `rpm2cpio` and `cpio`
- You can copy it from another RedHat installation
- You can copy it from another Linux installation for the same platform - there is a string possibility that it will work fine

Then you need to permanently modify the `PATH` environment variable so that the `rsync` command is found by your shell. If you do that for your user accounts in both servers, you can use `rsync` normally without the need for root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to install rsync on one server, that's all you need minimum.

If not, the question is what tools do you currently have available?  scp? sftp? ftp? ssh? telnet? find?